# Using zero-width assertions negative lookahead to match a string that does's contains string "abc"

Tags: java, regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

Hi all:
    I'm trying using zero-width assertions negative lookahead to match a string that does's contains string "abc",and this is what I got:

```
    Pattern pattern = new Perl5Compiler().compile("((?!abc).)+");
    Perl5Matcher matcher = new Perl5Matcher();
    System.out.println(matcher.matches("abc", pattern));
    System.out.println(matcher.matches("abdas dfas", pattern));
    System.out.println(matcher.matches("d abc ", pattern));
    System.out.println(matcher.matches("fafabcdef", pattern));
```

and the result is:

```
    false
    true
    false
    false
```

What I can't understand is why the string "abc" doesn't matches, it doesn't contains any character after the assertion "abc". Can anyone please figure out how this works? tks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look-arounds start doing their thing on positions, not on characters. So, with the string `"abc"`, this part of your regex: `(?!abc).` starts looking ahead on the *position* **before**  the `"a"` in your string. The position is the empty string before `"a"`. That's why it fails to match.

Comment: Thank for your answer, Bart! And what about the second string "abdasdfas"? According to what you say, this will fail to match too.

Comment: @khotyn, no, in the string `"abdasdfas"` there's no position (empty string) that has the sub-string `"abc"` in front of it, so that string would match.

Comment: thanks again, I think I got it, the first string fails because there is a sub-string "abc" after the empty string before "a", and thus the match fails. The key is that `(?!abc).` looks ahead `abc` after the empty string.

Comment: @khotyn, yes, you got it young grass-hopper! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hum, that differs from how Perl5 actually works.

```
$ perl -E'
    for ("abc", "abdas dfas", "d abc ", "fafabcdef") {
        say "$_: ", /((?!abc).)+/ ? "true ($&)" : "false";
    }
'
abc: true (bc)
vabdas dfas: true (abdas dfas)
d abc : true (d )
fafabcdef: true (faf)
```

It must have an implicit ^ and \z.

```
$ perl -E'
    for ("abc", "abdas dfas", "d abc ", "fafabcdef") {
        say "$_: ", /^((?!abc).)+\z/ ? "true ($&)" : "false";
    }
'
abc: false
abdas dfas: true (abdas dfas)
d abc : false
fafabcdef: false
```

The ones that don't match because there some position that matches /abc/.

Comment: Java's "own" `matches()` method validates/matches the entire string, so it indeed has implicit anchors. I would guess that the OP's (non-standard) `Perl5Matcher` class has them too.